# Parsing post data (PHP)

Tags: php, string

I'm new to PHP so not sure if I'm doing things right. I'm using PHP to process data and act as the main program between my database and my front-end, written in another language. As a basic test, I have my front-end posting 3 variables, separated by a pipe `|` symbol, all ints, e.g `60|1|5`. I've got as far as picking it up in my small PHP script using

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

And then just echoing it out. My other program then picks up the echo and confirms that it is being sent and received okay.

All of that works, I'm just not sure how in PHP I separate the 3 numbers and also I'm not sure if I need to add some security. These values would be sent automatically, so they're not input values, but it would probably be wise to learn how to do this securely anyway?

So, long question but basically, how do I separate `60|1|5` into `60`, `1` and `5` using PHP?

Comment: That's an odd way to post data.  You may consider posting in more conventional fashion (i.e query string, JSON-encoded string, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into it. At the moment is feels easiest for me to just post my values with a separator, but I'll take the advice and look into JSON etc and try to work out why people recommend it :)

Comment: PDO is a database library. What does it have to do with your question?

Comment: Sorry, should have said PHP. Getting confused, only started with it yesterday.

Comment: I believe you can edit your questions even with 1 point of rep. You should fix those confusing references to PDO.

Comment: Done (I think). I'm still not quite sure why my method isn't satisfactory. I have changed it to a JSON-encoded string, which also works fine, but is much more work at both ends and messy at the front-end and sends a much larger chunk of data. I suppose in larger sends JSON makes more sense, but for 3 or 4 pieces of data, is there anything actually 'wrong' with doing it my way?

Comment: What should happen with the pieces after you separated them?

Comment: I insert them into the database. The first piece is the ID, the 2nd and 3rd are altered values (coming in from my user screen). They're not inputted by the user, just altered through clicks (so less chance of an inject I think?).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode()`:

```
$parts = explode('|', $postdata);
echo $parts[0]; // 60
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

This has nothing to do with PDO.  PDO is for database functionality, not for general string manipulation.  Also, if the application sending the request can be modified, I recommend using a standard serialization format such as JSON.  What you have now will be ambiguous if your data has to contain a literal pipe `|`, and you don't want to invent your own serialization if you can help it.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm doing all of the work so I can alter the way it's sent. I'll look into JSON. Didn't know about Explode(), thanks, I'll look into that too :)